# "VirtualBox is configured with multiple host-only adapters with the same IP" when starting docker

Tags: docker, virtualbox

I am trying to run Docker on an old Mac OS.

I get this error:

> Error setting up host only network on machine start: VirtualBox is configured with multiple host-only adapters with the same IP "192.168.99.1". Please remove one

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue came from having run docker on two different sessions on my machine.

To fix it I ran: `VBoxManage list -l hostonlyifs` to identify adapters, and then removed the one I didn't need anymore:

```
VBoxManage hostonlyif remove vboxnet1
```

Alternatively, if you want to be able to run Docker from two different sessions, you can change the IP address of each adapter:

- Go to File -> Host Network Manager
- Change the IP address of one of the adapters

Comment: This just saved me a rebuild of my minishift environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue come up as well when using Local by Flywheel.

I have two different user accounts on my Mac. One for personal, one for work. I was still logged in to my work account when trying to start up a machine on my personal account.

After making sure I was completely logged out of my work account and restarted, I was able to get it working again on my personal account.

Before doing this I noticed that my IPv4 Address/Mask under Host Network Manager was the same. After having logged out and restarted, it is now different and I no longer am getting the notice when starting Local by Flywheel.

Hope this helps someone out!

Answer (score 0):

This Error happens because you have  already virtualbox installed in your computer.

Here is the simple step.

Step 1: Uninstall Virtualbox from Your Computer

Steps 2: Uninstall Docker and Re-Install It

Fixed!!!