# docker problem on mac terminal: ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock

Tags: docker, macos, terminal

I am using docker with k8s from mac terminal. Don't know what I have done, my docker command does not work anymore. For example, `docker info` and `docker run...` hang forever. I've tried to fix this problem by uninstalling and installing docker. But after I reinstalled docker, I got this error message:

```bash
$ docker info Client:  Context:    default  Debug Mode: false

Server: ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at
unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? errors
pretty printing info
```

For other docker commands, I also received:

```bash
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

I've read through lots of websites ([How to easily install and uninstall docker on MacOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346109/how-to-easily-install-and-uninstall-docker-on-macos)) (["VirtualBox is configured with multiple host-only adapters with the same IP" when starting docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55573426/virtualbox-is-configured-with-multiple-host-only-adapters-with-the-same-ip-whe))..., but still unable to fix my problem. A lot of solutions do not seem to work on macos. I've seen many solved by the `systemctl` command, and I tried to replace that with `launchctl` and followed the rest of the instructions. ([Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:/var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker)) But none works for me.
Please help solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just found out that I have to restart my docker desktop as well. I had no idea that docker desktop and terminal's docker command are related. But now, apparently, they are related. If anyone encounters similar problems, remember to try restart your docker desktop and wait for it to get running!

Comment: Restart didn't work for me. so I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76219883/9445226

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871479/docker-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon , or https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/373914 . When you restarted your docker desktop you probably started the daemon that was missing.

Answer (score -3):

```
chown root:docker /var/run/docker.sock    
chmod g+w /var/run/docker.sock
```

**Try to give/Modify Permission.**